# PySpark - Get aggregated values for dynamic columns in a dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with the below rows:

```
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| label| machine| value1| value2|
+------+--------+-------+-------+
|label1|machine1|     13|    7.5|
|label1|machine1|     9 |    7.5|
|label1|machine1|    8.5|    7.5|
|label1|machine1|   10.5|    7.5|
|label1|machine1|     12|      8|
|label1|machine2|     8 |   13.5|
|label1|machine2|     18|     10|
|label1|machine2|     10|     14|
|label1|machine2|     9 |   10.5|
|label1|machine2|    8.5|     10|
|label2|machine3|     8 |    7.5|
|label2|machine3|     18|    7.5|
|label2|machine3|     10|    7.5|
|label2|machine3|     9 |    7.5|
|label2|machine3|    8.5|      8|
|label2|machine4|   13.5|     13|
|label2|machine4|     10|      9|
|label2|machine4|     14|    8.5|
|label2|machine4|   10.5|   10.5|
|label2|machine4|     10|     12|
+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Here, I can have multiple value columns other than `value1, value2` in the data frame. For every column, I want to aggregate the values with `collect_list` and create a new column in the data frame, so that I can perform some functions later.

For this, I tried like this:

```
my_df = my_df.groupBy(['label', 'machine']). \
     agg(collect_list("value1").alias("col_value1"), collect_list("value2").alias("col_value2"))
```

It is giving me the below 4 rows as I'm grouping by `label` and `machine` columns.

```
+------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
| label| machine|    collected_value1|    collected_value2|
+------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
|label1|machine1|[13.0, 9.0, 8.5, ...|[7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7...|
|label2|machine2|[8.0, 18.0, 10.0,...|[13.5, 10.0, 14, ...|
|label1|machine3|[8.0, 18.0, 10.0,...|[7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7...|
|label2|machine4|[13.5, 10.0, 14, ...|[13.0, 9.0, 8.5, ...|
+------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Now, my problem here is how to pass columns dynamically to this group by. The columns might differ for every run, so I want to use something like this:

```
df_cols = ['value1', 'value2']

my_df = my_df.groupBy(['label', 'machine']). \
    agg(collect_list(col_name).alias(str(col_name+"_collected")) for col_name in df_cols)
```

It gives me `AssertionError: all exprs should be Column` error.

How can I achieve this? Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `.agg(*[collect_list(col_name).alias(str(col_name+"_collected")) for col_name in df_cols])`  or `.agg(*[collect_list(col_name).alias(f"{col_name}_collected") for col_name in df_cols])` after the groupby as an aggregation

Comment: Thanks, just tried the same before checking your reply and it worked like a charm,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code has worked. Thank you.

```
exprs = [collect_list(x).alias(str(x+"_collected")) for x in df_cols]
my_df = my_df.groupBy(['label', 'machine']).agg(*exprs)
```